# Monitor TFS Service Hooks/Web hooks

Tags: tfs, webhooks

I have some Web Hooks setup to push data to my custom endpoint during certain events.  If my service is unavailable for some reason the web hook will go offline and I need to manually go to the web page inside of TFS and re-enable it.  I wasn't able to find a way to queue items or auto-retry later.

Assuming it doesn't have an option for queuing and re-trying, is there a way I can automate:
1. Check each of the web hooks to determine if they are enabled
2. Re-Enable if after a period of time

I'm using on-prem TFS V15 (from help about)

Answer (score 0):

There is not any configure to never auto-disable serviceHooks when encounter errors. You may have to re-enable the disable web hooks in this case.

You could try to enable web hooks through this REST API: [Update a subscription](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/hooks/subscriptions#update-a-subscription).

```
Put https://[account].visualstudio.com/_apis/hooks/subscriptions/[subscription id]?api-version=1.0
```

Body (Content-Type:application/json)

```
{
  "publisherId": "tfs",
  "eventType": "build.complete",
  "resourceVersion": "1.0-preview.1",
  "consumerId": "webHooks",
  "consumerActionId": "httpRequest",
  "scope":1,
  "status":0,
  "publisherInputs": {
    "buildStatus": "",
    "definitionName":"ClassTestVNext",
    "projectId": "578ca584-4268-4ba2-b579-7aaee499c306"
  },
  "consumerInputs":{"url":"http://XXXX/"}
}
```

You could also use F12 in chrome, choose network  to capture the request info when you do the re-enable action.